# Looping through in web scraping in r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to we scrape a list of drugs from the bnf website https://bnf.nice.org.uk/drug/

Let's take carbamazepine as an example- https://bnf.nice.org.uk/drug/carbamazepine.html#indicationsAndDoses

I want the following code to loop through each of the indications within that drug and return the patient type and dosage for each of those indications. This is a problem when I finally want to make it a dataframe because there are 7 indications and around 9 patient types and dosages.

Currently, I get an indications variable which looks like-

```
[1] "Focal and secondary generalised tonic-clonic seizures"  
[2] "Primary generalised tonic-clonic seizures"              
[3] "Trigeminal neuralgia"                                   
[4] "Prophylaxis of bipolar disorder unresponsive to lithium"
[5] "Adjunct in acute alcohol withdrawal "                   
[6] "Diabetic neuropathy"                                    
[7] "Focal and generalised tonic-clonic seizures"
```

And a patient group variable which looks like-

```
[1] "For \n                        Adult\n                    "                 
[2] "For \n                        Elderly\n                    "               
[3] "For \n                        Adult\n                    "                 
[4] "For \n                        Adult\n                    "                 
[5] "For \n                        Adult\n                    "                 
[6] "For \n                        Adult\n                    "                 
[7] "For \n                        Adult\n                    "                 
[8] "For \n                        Child 1 month–11 years\n                    "
[9] "For \n                        Child 12–17 years\n                    "
```

I want it is as follows-

```
Indication                                                         Pt group     
[1] "Focal and secondary generalised tonic-clonic seizures"       For Adult
[1] "Focal and secondary generalised tonic-clonic seizures"       For elderly
[2] "Primary generalised tonic-clonic seizures"                   For Adult
```

and so on..

Here is my code-

```
url_list <- paste0("https://bnf.nice.org.uk/drug/", druglist, ".html#indicationsAndDoses")

url_list


## The scraping bit - we are going to extract key bits of information for each drug in the list and craete a data frame

drug_table <- data.frame() # an empty data frame


for(i in seq_along(url_list)){
i=15
## Extract drug name
drug <- read_html(url_list[i]) %>%
  html_nodes("span") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  .[7]



## Extract indication

indication <- read_html(url_list[i]) %>%
  html_nodes(".indication") %>%
  html_text()%>%
unique




## Extact patient group
for (j in seq_along(length(indication))){
pt_group <- read_html(url_list[i]) %>%
  html_nodes(".patientGroupList") %>%
  html_text()




ln <- length(pt_group)


## Extract dose info per pateint group
dose <- read_html(url_list[i]) %>%
  html_nodes("p") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  .[2:(1+ln)]





## Combine pt group and dose
dose1 <- cbind(pt_group, dose)

}
## Create the data frame

drug_df <- data.frame(Drug = drug, Indication = indication, Dose = dose1) 


## Combine data
drug_table <- bind_rows(drug_table, drug_df)

}
```

Comment: tl;dr. Can you not boil it down further to the essence of what you are asking for?

Comment: In essence I want to web scrape the bnf page to get a table looking similar to table 3 in the question above for each of the drug types. I have just provided the code I am using but am happy to use any alternative approaches as well

Answer (score 0):

That site is actually blocked for me! I can't see anything there, but I can tell you, basically, it should be done like this.

The html_nodes() function turns each HTML tag into a row in an R dataframe.

```
library(rvest)

## Loading required package: xml2

# Define the url once.
URL <- "https://scistarter.com/finder?phrase=&lat=&lng=&activity=At%20the%20beach&topic=&search_filters=&search_audience=&page=1#view-projects"

    scistarter_html <- read_html(URL)
    scistarter_html

## {xml_document}
## <html class="no-js" lang="en">
## [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset= ...
## [2] <body>\n    \n    \n    <svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; he ...
```

We’re able to retrieve the same HTML code we saw in our browser. This is not useful yet, but it does show that we’re able to retrieve the same HTML code we saw in our browser. Now we will begin filtering through the HTML to find the data we’re after.

The data we want are stored in a table, which we can tell by looking at the “Inspect Element” window.

This grabs all the nodes that have links in them.

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <a href="/index.html" class="site-header__branding" title="go to the ...
## [2] <a href="/dashboard">My Account</a>
## [3] <a href="/finder" class="is-active">Project Finder</a>
## [4] <a href="/events">Event Finder</a>
## [5] <a href="/people-finder">People Finder</a>
## [6] <a href="#dialog-login" rel="modal:open">log in</a>
```

In a more complex example, we could use this to “crawl” the page, but that’s for another day.

Every div on the page:

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("div") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <div class="site-header__nav js-hamburger b-utility">\n        <butt ...
## [2] <div class="site-header__nav__body js-hamburger__body">\n          < ...
## [3] <div class="nav-tools">\n            <div class="nav-tools__search"> ...
## [4] <div class="nav-tools__search">\n              <div class="field">\n ...
## [5] <div class="field">\n                <form method="get" action="/fin ...
## [6] <div class="input-group input-group--flush">\n                    <d ...

… the nav-tools div. This calls by css where class=nav-tools.

    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("div.nav-tools") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <div class="nav-tools">\n            <div class="nav-tools__search"> ...

We can call the nodes by id as follows.

    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("div#project-listing") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (1)}
## [1] <div id="project-listing" class="subtabContent">\n          \n       ...
```

All the tables as follows:

```
    scistarter_html %>%
      html_nodes("table") %>%
      head()

## {xml_nodeset (6)}
## [1] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [2] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [3] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [4] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [5] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
## [6] <table class="table-project-2-col u-mb-0">\n<legend class="u-visuall ...
```

See the (related) link below, for more info.

https://rpubs.com/Radcliffe/superbowl